# Install-free database for nhibernate with multithread access and ACID transactions

Tags: c#, wpf, database, nhibernate

I have a small program in C# that checks web pages on some interval in a multithreaded fashion. It also uses NHibernate as ORM engine and currently uses SQL Server.
To allow a simple install to my users, I'd like to use a lighter database that does not need to be installed, but it should allow my application to continue multi-threaded and with ACID transactions.
What database should I use? Remember, I do not want my clients to install any dbms software, just copy app folder and run.

Comment: You should take a look at SQLite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SQLite](http://nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite) or [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact).

Comment: I'm using SQLite now with no complaints. Also using FluentMigrations allowed me to quickly duplicate my existing SQL Server database and small changes to nhibernate.config allowed me to seamlessly transition databases.